# English Usage: what are the best dictionaries/online sources?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, dictionaries

I have problem with word usage.  Am I angry/furious/enraged?  Did he threaten to castigate/reprimand/admonish/rebuke/punish me?  And I was surprised/puzzled/disconcerted...since/due to the fact that/because of...?

In addition, I often mix formal and informal language.  Or formal with literal.  For instance when you type "sunder" in google, it is noted that this is a "literary" verb; "peruse" is "formal"; while "exacerbate" is apparently neither.  Different sites have different views on these distinctions.

Some of these issues have, recently became more relevant for me (or is it pertinent?) when I started to relearn French.  It has forced me to look at my English usage.  And discover a lot of holes there.

Anyhow, appreciate suggestions, links, references to books, dictionaries, etc.  Especially sources that make reference to etymology, as I find that helps me get a better grasp of difference in word usage.

p.s. I just want to add that what I've been doing so far is I've been picking up bits and pieces of info from various online dictionaries (including stackexchange), but the process has been too time-consuming and inexact.  To spend half an hour searching all over the place for a single usage question and sift through pages of differing views and opinions, is a sure way to exhaust yourself and give up all together.

Comment: There is a list of dictionaries on meta: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available

Comment: There's probably no one best dictionary. Or rather OED is probably the best, but 1) seeing a definition by another lesser dictionary may still give you nuance you didn't realize. 2) It's not perfect; it doesn't give things like informal or infrequent except when extreme. and 3) is only accessible online through a public library. But when you compare with others, they just aren't as good as OED. Google isn't terrible in that it gives you a bunch of links to definitions for which you should look at all, not just their top one (or their sumary).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sure, but at least try to be welcoming. First time users have no idea what your 'rules' are.

Comment: Hello, Jlente. May I suggest that you look in the Help Center to discover the type of question that ELU values. Unfortunately, this question is not about English language and usage within the scope prescribed there.

Comment: @Mitch They're your rules as much as anyone else's. I'm wondering why you haven't seen fit to toe the site line and close-vote.

Comment: Thank you Mitch, I quite appreciate your attitude, that despite some disagreements about appropriateness of my question, you tried to be helpful to me.  I had thought my question was relevant, I had quickly searched question titles for "English usage" and dictionary references, nothing had come up, so I had posed my question.  I had not visited the help center, and did not know my question would be problematic.  But as it stands, I got some relevant and helpful replies, and I leave it up to you guys how you like to handle it, I'm fine either way.  Also thanks to Helmar for that suggestion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are no behavioral rules here, only suggestions or guidelines. That initial comment could be worded a little less blunt.

Comment: I think your main problem is that you are using the internet.  This chaining of looking up one thing after another can also occur when using a print dictionary, but nowhere near as much as with an online dictionary.  Just go to one or two bookstores where you live, and spend an hour comparing the dictionaries they have on the shelf.  Pick one that has plenty of usage examples, and that you feel comfortable with.  Then, for 90% of your word research needs, you'll be able to use your print dictionary.

Comment: Once in a while you'll find it's not helping and you need to do further research, with the internet.  But be aware of your tendencies to start wandering here and there, and to get bogged down.  You can set yourself a time limit.

Comment: Reward your self-discipline with the occasional, well-defined splurge afternoon on https://www.usingenglish.com/.

Comment: @Mitch 'This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.' is not my invention. Perhaps you could direct criticism more judiciously.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting and helpful resource not mentioned in @Helmar's reference (btw, thanks for that) is http://www.snappywords.com/, a visual dictionary and thesaurus.  It's color-coded for part of speech and attribute relationships.  Hover over a term for a definition and usage; double-click to expand the tree from a node.